# Is there a Main()-like function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, program-entry-point

I've started to write code in TypeScript for 3 days. I have completed all my class designs but at this point I'm writing the main function. Everything is nice but somebody have to run the Main() function. I do this with this way;

- by calling directly **Main();**

I'm just curious about that is there any method which is not triggered by me ? or How do you handle your Main() methods when typing your code in TypeScript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike class-based languages, `JavaScript` does not require a `main` method.

Since TypeScript is a super-set of `JavaScript`, all JavaScript code is also valid TypeScript, and therefore doesn't need a main.

So, you can call your Object (JavaScript) or Class (TypeScript) anything you'd like -- `Main`, `DoThis` or even `ServeMeADrink` and all are equally valid and can be invoked by calling, just as you've done.

They can also be invoked by:

- event handlers
- A framework's system, such as the `data-main` attribute used by some MVC/JavaScript systems.

Comment: You are right! This is useful. Event handlers look like a good choice. With these line of code is actually does what I want - window.addEventListener("load",Main,false); -

Answer (score 7):

TypeScript, as JavaScript, doesn't have a main function. The code is executed from top to bottom, so you can just create the function and call it at the end of the main file, after the imports.